# how to revert a previous commit without geting a detached HEAD

Tags: git, github

I want to revert the previous commit back to my project.
I tried
`git checkout <hash>`
but i get a detached HEAD which means that i have to create a new branch when i commit the code again after i've worked on it.

Comment: `revert` has a technical meaning that is different than `reset`.  It sounds like you want to reset.

Comment: they both work fine for me thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I revert a Git repository to a previous commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/how-do-i-revert-a-git-repository-to-a-previous-commit)

Comment: @parkourkarthik it partialy does but it does not answer how not to get a detached HEAD

Comment: It does because you did `checkout`, which means : "bring me back to a specific revision of my history, so I can check it out". It will, repopulating your working dir with the files of this revision, but won't alter your history. Since you've asked for a hash and not a branch name, you're no longer tied to a branch if you commit from here, hence being in "detached mode". You come back to attached mode (tied to a branch) when you check out a branch name, which leads you back to the tip of this branch.

Answer (score 0):

Use `git reset` to make your branch head point to an earlier commit.

Comment: thanks it worked.

Comment: @lirdi https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: i can't vote it because i don't have enough reputation